# How to initialize ApplicationContext and/or Environment

Tags: micronaut

The typical application entry point looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Micronaut.run(Application.class);
}
```

However, the docs indicate that the environment and application context can be customized:

For example, https://docs.micronaut.io/1.1.0.M1/guide/index.html#propertySource,

```
void initializeTheEnvironment() {
    ...
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = ApplicationContext.run(
            PropertySource.of(
                    "test",
                    CollectionUtils.mapOf(
                        "micronaut.server.host", "foo",
                        "micronaut.server.port", 8080
                    )
            ),
            "test", "android");
    Environment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();

    ... what to put here to then run the application using the customizations above ... ?
}
```

If I:
- customize the Environment (similar to above)
- inject an instance of the Environment into a Controller
- then, to start the app, I simply continue to use Micronaut.run()

... then I can see that my customizations are not visible in the injected Environment instance.

The question: given an initialized ApplicationContext and/or Environment, how do I then run the application using that environment?

Is there a way to pass these constructed objects into Micronaut.run(...) ?

Is this unnecessary because Micronaut somehow behind the scenes picks up the already-initialized object instances?

I'm probably missing something very obvious or this is simply not an expected way of using the framework, but I am curious since the docs explicitly call this customization out in a few places...

Comment: Are you just trying to configure one environment? Why programmatically? You can use the application.yml for this. You can also use runtime configurations _or_ bash scripts to set environment variables and load them into the .yml  with  ${} syntax.  Or you can set which .yml to use (section 4.2 "Included PropertySource Loaders" very bottom 'hint' text).

Comment: Thanks James and Brooks. I'm just trying to better understand how the underlying architecture works. I agree we wouldn't likely manually configure environments etc normally, but I was confused why the examples illustrate this and then I couldn't figure out how to drop that into my test app. Of course, once I saw James' reply below it's obvious !

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following to achieve what you want:

```
Micronaut.build()
    .mainClass(Application.class)
    .propertySources(PropertySource.of(
        "test",
        CollectionUtils.mapOf(
            "micronaut.server.host", "foo",
            "micronaut.server.port", 8080
        )
    ))
    .environments("test", "android")
    .start()
```

Comment: Yes, this is so obvious once you posted :) Thank you James!